# Azure Data Factory - Copy Activity Json Array

Tags: mongodb, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to pull data from MongoDB in Azure Data Factory V2. The data structure is some thing like below.

```
{
   "Username":"Joe",
   "Cities"["Delhi","Mumbai"]
}
```

Now I wan't to do the cross-apply and get the data as given below.

```
Name | City
----------
Joe  | Delhi
Joe  | Mumbai
```

I have already read the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping), but I'm not able to find a solution for this particular array structure.

Comment: any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Check the example for mongo db to oracle.

CollectionReference is what you wanted.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-schema-and-type-mapping#alternative-schema-mapping

Comment: I got a reply from microsoft team, that this array of string is not yet supported. But array of object can be retrived. example: {"Cities"[{"City":"Delhi"},{"City":"Mumbai"}]} here the City can be retrived using collection reference. But thanks for your help